# Load data using Meteor.call on load

Tags: meteor

When trying to render my template, i want to load the data from the server. I'm trying to use Meteor.call but as per the documentation, i'm clearly not in a stub.

If I use Meteor.call inside of an event handler, the response i get back is correct. If i call it within the template.created or similar, i get an undefined response. I guess i could use async call to do it and then render it when available. But is there another way?

I don't want the clients to have direct access to the DB, i want it to come from the server.

```
  //This doesn't work
  Template.config.created = function() {
    console.log(Meteor.call('getValue')); //returns undefined
  };

   //This works
   Template.config.events({
    'blur #button' : function () {
      console.log(Meteor.call('getValue')); //Prints value
    }
```

Any clues?

D

Comment: Another note is that in Meteor clients never actually have direct access to the DB, even when using the client-side DB API. All queries will be checked against the allow/deny rules that you specify. This gives you full ACL control over what queries the client is allowed to run. At the very least, you should define method stubs on the client so it can do latency compensation, making your app feel much less sluggish when compared to waiting on server method responses.

Comment: Adding to Cuberto -- by default Meteor has autopublish and insecure turned on, which publishes all data to all clients and allows the client full access. You can turn these off using $ meteor remove <package_name> and publish/subscribe on the data you need. Here's a pretty decent article: http://andrewscala.com/meteor/

Comment: The two answers below nail it. So do the clarifications above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a callback in your **Meteor.call**

```
Template.config.created = function() {
    Meteor.call('getValue', function(error, data) {
        if(error){
            //do stuff to handle error
        }
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer. Should i setup Reactivity so that when the call has completed, it'll update the template?

Comment: That is typically what would be done. The easiest and most common way would be to simply do a `Session.set()` in the callback and a `Session.get()` in a template helper function.

Comment: I'd recommend setting a template helper that returns a collection (which are reactive by default) https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-look-at-a-meteor-template/  -- see the section about "Template Helpers".  Otherwise using a session (Cuberto's suggestion will work for you)

Comment: @hharnisc Yeah, it's hard to tell which method the OP needs without more information about what the method actually does. It should also be mentioned that a combined approach is often useful, where a session variable is used as part of the selector for a helper function's `find()` call.

Comment: Thanks folks. Working fine with Session now. In template.created i fire off the call, then set the session, then get the session in my helper.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> On the client, if you do not pass a callback and you are not inside a stub, `call` will return `undefined`, and you will have no way to get the return value of the method. That is because the client doesn't have fibers, so there is not actually any way it can block on the remote execution of a method.

I'm not sure why your event handler call is working... There isn't any way to synchronously get a server response like that in JavaScript without Fibers. The solution is simply to provide an asynchronous callback. This isn't really a Meteor limitation, it's just a JavaScript limitation.

Comment: Thanks, i was being thick. Clearly just needed some time away from the screen!